# enable searching feature from any index ajaxToolkit ListSearchExtender

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using `ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender` in a dropdown. It has the feature "*search as you type*", like if I type any word it shows the list starting with that word.

But my requirement is that I need the list of all the items that contain the typed word. For example, if I type *A*, I want all the countries name that contain the word A anywhere.

Currently `ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender` shows only the countries name starting with letter A.

How can I make this ListSearchExtender to search any items in the drop-down that contain the typed word but not just only at the beginning of the item?

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for that type of search.

I would recommend using [AutoCompleteExtender](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) for that.